# Double click the datagrid in jeasyui popup not opened in Firefox

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using the jQuery EasyUI Datagird (http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=) for my website. When I double click the each records a popup should be opened in IE, Chrome, Safari except firefox?

Clicking event function is fired, data populating place is having issue.

### First, I can load the data here:

```
function loadMailDetails(rowIndex){
    var t = $('#test');
    t.datagrid('clearSelections');
    t.datagrid('selectRow',rowIndex);
    var row = $('#test').datagrid('getSelected');

    if (row){
        var folderId=$('#sourceFolderid').val();
        var isArchive=$('#archiving').val();
        var loading=fromLoad;
        if(isArchive=="no")
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:'id=' +row.id+'&folderid='+folderId+"&loading="+loading+"&ummId="+row.ummId,
                url:'/'+productName+'/inbox/getEmailDetail',
                success:function(data,textStatus){
                    mailDetails(data,row);
                },
                async:false ,
                cache: false
            });

        }
        else
        {

            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:'id=' +row.id+'&folderid='+folderId+'&ummId='+row.ummId,
                url:'/'+productName+'/inbox/getArchiveEmailMessage',
                success:function(data,textStatus){
                    mailDetails(data,row);
                },
                async:false ,
                cache: false
            });

        }
    }
}
```

### Here i can open the Popup (issue happened here)

```
 if(fromAutoMatch==false)
        {
jQuery.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'/'+productName+'/inbox/openMailPopupDialog',
                success:function(data,textStatus){
                    $('body').append(data);
                },
                async: false
            });

            var folderId=$('#sourceFolderid').val();
            var isArchive=$('#archiving').val();
            var selectedNode = $('#jqueryTree').tree('getSelected')
            var selectedText = selectedNode.text;
            var tempDrafts  = false;
            if(selectedText.indexOf("Drafts") >=0){
              tempDrafts = true;
            }
           var loading=fromLoad;
            if (rowData){
                if(isArchive=="no"){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'id=' +rowData.id+'&folderid='+folderId+"&isdraft="+tempDrafts+"&loading="+loading,
                        url:'/'+productName+'/inbox/getEmailDetail',
                        success:function(data,textStatus){
                            mailPopup(data);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'id=' +rowData.id+'&folderid='+folderId,
                        url:'/'+productName+'/inbox/getArchiveEmailMessage',
                        success:function(data,textStatus){
                            mailPopup(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        },
        onRowContextMenu:function(e,rowIndex,rowData){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#test').datagrid('selectRow',rowIndex);
            var noOfRows = $('#test').datagrid('getSelections').length;
            var selectedNode = $('#jqueryTree').tree('getSelected')
            var selectedText = selectedNode.text;
            var tempNode = $('#jqueryTree').tree('getParent',selectedNode.target);
            var parentText = tempNode.text;
            if(selectedText.indexOf("Drafts") >= 0 || selectedText.indexOf("Outbox") >= 0 || selectedText.indexOf("Sent Items") >= 0 || selectedText.indexOf("Deleted Items") >= 0 || selectedText.indexOf("Failed Items") >= 0 
                || parentText.indexOf("Drafts") >= 0 || parentText.indexOf("Outbox") >= 0 || parentText.indexOf("Sent Items") >= 0 || parentText.indexOf("Deleted Items") >= 0 || parentText.indexOf("Failed Items") >= 0){
                $('#archiveEmailRightClickID').css('display','none');
            }
            if(noOfRows==1)

            {
                if(rowData.Read==true)
                {
                    $('#markAsRead').css('display','none');
                    $('#markAsReadId').css('display','none');
                    $('#markAsUnread').css('display','block');
                    $('#markAsUnreadId').css('display','block');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#markAsRead').css('display','block');
                    $('#markAsReadId').css('display','block');
                    $('#markAsUnread').css('display','none');
                    $('#markAsUnreadId').css('display','none');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $('#markAsRead').css('display','block');
                $('#markAsUnread').css('display','block');
                $('#markAsReadId').css('display','block');
                $('#markAsUnreadId').css('display','block');
            }
            var selectedAccordion = $('#accordionPanel').accordion('getSelected');
            var selectedIndex
            if (selectedAccordion){
                selectedIndex = $('#accordionPanel').accordion('getPanelIndex', selectedAccordion);
            }
            if(selectedIndex == 1){
                $('#gridContextMenu').menu().menu('show',{
                    left: e.pageX,
                    top: e.pageY
                });
            }else if(selectedIndex == 2){
                $('#gridContextArchiveMenu').menu().menu('show',{
                    left: e.pageX,
                    top: e.pageY
                });
            }
        },
        //         ,
        rowStyler:function(index,row){
            if ((row.Read == false || row.Read == "false" || row.Read == "[false]") 
                && (row.emailSource == "2" || row.emailSource == 2 || row.emailSource == "[2]")){
                return 'font-weight:bold;background-color:#a7cdf0;';
            }else if ((row.Read == false || row.Read == "false" || row.Read == "[false]") 
                && (row.emailSource != "2" || row.emailSource != 2 || row.emailSource != "[2]")){
                return 'font-weight:bold;';
            }else if ((row.Read == true || row.Read == "true" || row.Read == "[true]") 
                && (row.emailSource == "2" || row.emailSource == 2 || row.emailSource == "[2]")){
                return 'background-color:#a7cdf0;';
            }
        },
        onClickRow:function(rowIndex,rowData){
            additionaldata =  rowData;
            loadMailDetails(rowIndex)

        },
        onDblClickCell  :function(rowIndex, field, value){
            if(field=="autoMatch")
                 fromAutoMatch=true;
            else
                 fromAutoMatch=false;
        },
        onBeforeLoad:function(){
            var rows = $('#test').datagrid('getSelections');
            if(rows){
                $('#test').datagrid('clearSelections');
                $('#test').datagrid('clearChecked');
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround your code in `onClickRow` with `setTimeout( [your code], 0);`.